# Database Records on Page Load - Dynamic Text Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with dynamically created text fields.  Most solutions I have found thus far have been related to retaining view state on postback, but I believe I have taken care of that issue.  On postback, the values that are in the text fields are retained.

The issue I am having:  I can't get the database values currently stored to load in the dynamic fields.  I am currently calling loadUpdates() to try to do this, but unsure how to grab the data row, while also making sure I can continue to add new fields (or remove them).  How can I achieve this?

"txtProjectsUpdate" is the text field, "hidFKID" is the foreign key to a parent table, and "hidUpdateID" is the hidden value of the primary key in the child table (the values I am attempting to load).

Markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddTextBox" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddTextBox_Click" />
    <asp:Placeholder ID="placeHolderControls" runat="server"/>
</div>

<asp:TextBox runat = "server" ID = "hidUpdateID" />
<asp:HiddenField runat = "server" ID = "hidFKID" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
                AddTextBox(i);
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = selectDetails();
            tryHidFKID(hidFKID, dt.Rows[0]["fkprjNumber"].ToString());


            loadUpdates();
        }
    }

protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTextBox(TextBoxCount);
        TextBoxCount++;
    }

    private int TextBoxCount
    {
        get
        {
            var count = ViewState["txtBoxCount"];
            return (count == null) ? 0 : (int)count;
        }
        set { ViewState["txtBoxCount"] = value; }
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btnRemove = sender as Button;
        if (btnRemove == null) return;
        btnRemove.Parent.Visible = false;
    }

    private void AddTextBox(int index)
    {
        var panel = new Panel();
        panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox
        {
            ID = string.Concat("txtProjectUpdates", index),
            Rows = 5,
            Columns = 130,
            TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine,
            CssClass = "form-control",
            MaxLength = 500
        });

        panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox
        {
            ID = string.Concat("hidUpdateID", index)
        });

        var btn = new Button { Text = "Remove" };
        btn.Click += btnRemove_Click;
        panel.Controls.Add(btn);
        placeHolderControls.Controls.Add(panel);
    }

protected void loadUpdates()
    {
        DataTable dt = dbClass.ExecuteDataTable
        (
            "spSelectRecords", <db>, new SqlParameter[1]
            {
                new SqlParameter ("@vFKPrjNumber", hidFKID.Value)
            }
        );
            AddTextBox(TextBoxCount);
            TextBoxCount++;
    }
protected void tryHidFKID(HiddenField hidFKID, string txtSelected)
    {
        try
        {
            hidFKID.Value = txtSelected;
        }
        catch
        {
            hidFKID.Value = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you stepped through this code at all..?

Comment: Yes.  On page load, if there are say, 3 database records, what I see initially is 3 empty text fields.  And, I can add or remove new rows, and their values are retained on postback.